# plotting the data frame that returned from summarize function

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, dplyr

I want to plot the Emission of a Pollutant across different years so I used `dplyr` package to summarize the data but I'm not able to plot it because of the format of the returned `dataframe`.

I tried to convert the year and emission lists using `as.numeric` but it refused so what should I do ?

```r
total_emmision_per_year <- SCC %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(total_emmision_per_year = sum(Emissions)) 
plot(total_emmision_per_year[,1], total_emmision_per_year[,2] , pch = 19)
```

I get this error:

> Error in stripchart.default(x1, ...) : invalid plotting method

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mohy! Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`). Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: This is because `summarise` returns a tibble and the columns are not vectors, which `plot` expects. So either add `%>% as.data.frame()` to the end of the first line, or use `ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_point()`, where x and y are the names of columns 1 and 2, instead.

Comment: To further illustrate the point, see how `mtcars[,1]` (a frame) differs from `as.tibble(mtcars)[,1]` (a tibble).

Answer (score 0):

As it was said on the comments, the issue is because you have a tibble
If you want to extract a vector from a tibble, you can use the pull function from tibble package. The following code might work if you want to plot using the base package. (although I would recommend using ggplot2, as neilfws suggest)

```
 library(tibble)
 plot(total_emmision_per_year %>% pull(1), total_emmision_per_year %>% pull(2) , pch = 19)
```

Comment: If the answer was good, you can upvote it. If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as solved. Doing so, you help the other users on this community. Thanks

Comment: I did but I'm new so I can't do this right now but I record the upvote. Can you please have a look in this low quality plots problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57512755/low-quality-of-line-charts?noredirect=1#comment101501212_57512755