# low quality of line charts

Tags: r, plot

any line chart that i do is edgy and has low quality when it's in png format i tried pdf and it was very smooth and nice.

[image: here is the plot]

i have tried Cairo package but it gave me only black photo

this is my code originally that gives low quality

```
plot(total_emmision_per_year[,1], (total_emmision_per_year[,2])/1000 , type = "b" , pch =19 , xlab = "Years" , ylab = "Emmision" , main = "Emissions across years")

dev.copy(png , file = "plot1_base_plot.png")
dev.off()
```

and i tried :

```
library(Cairo)
Cairo(file="plot1_line.png", 
      type="png",
      units="in", 
      width=100, 
      height=100, 
      pointsize=12, 
      dpi=72)
dev.off()
```

edit :
i also tried  to apply Cairo package on ggplot and nothing happened here is the code :

```
line_colors <- c("steelblue","red","steelblue","steelblue")

ggplot(total_emission_from_coal_combustion , aes(years,emissions/100)) +
  geom_point(shape =19) +
  geom_line(size =1.1 , col =line_colors ) +
  ggtitle("total emission of coal combustion-related sources") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  ylab("emissions") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c(1999,2002,2005,2008))

library(Cairo)
Cairo(file="x.png", 
      type="png",
      units="in", 
      width=300, 
      height=300, 
      pointsize=12, 
      dpi=72)
dev.off()
```

[image: ggplot line chart]

Comment: You use `width=100` (and `height=`), increasing them will improve the image quality.

Comment: R base graphics does not use anti-aliasing algorithms. If you use base R you are stuck with that.

Comment: Try using plotly. Their graphs are pretty good.

Comment: I tend to up the resolution and use a compression option to get the file size down..

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a resolution issue. 72 dpi is quite low. Try setting "dpi=300" and seeing if it improves.See also this [Blog Post](https://thepoliticalmethodologist.com/2013/11/25/making-high-resolution-graphics-for-academic-publishing/)

Comment: once i increase the dpi it gives me an error :  ```Error in Cairo(file = "x.png", type = "png", units = "in", width = 300,  : 
  Failed to create Cairo backend! ```

Answer (score 1):

i solved the problem using type = "cairo" within the png funcrion and the res argument also to control the resolution

```
 png(filename = "plot4.png",
 width =600, height = 600, units = "px", pointsize = 12,
 res = 130,type ="cairo")  

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(total_emission_from_coal_combustion , aes(years,emissions/100)) +
geom_point(shape =19) +
geom_line(size =1.1 , col =line_colors ) +
ggtitle("total emission of coal combustion-related sources") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
ylab("emissions") +
scale_x_discrete(limits = c(1999,2002,2005,2008))

dev.off()
```